# For Loop Decreasing Caffeine Content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how to write this in javascript. The idea is that it takes the time and caffeine content, uses a loop to decrease hourly until it gets to 20mg and then stops and tells you what time it is that you reached the half life (at 5 hours) and then your bedtime at 20mg.

I have a not even functioning for loop at the moment. I'm trying to wrap my head around how to condition the for loop. Do I put in values of the caffeine or hours?

Here is what I have:

```
function brew() {
    var lastTime = 15; // military time for 3pm
    var lastCoffee = 150; // 150mg of caffeine 

    for (var i = 1; lastCoffee <= 20; i++) {
        var caffeine = lastCoffee/2; // my bootleg half life equation    
    };
}
```

Comment: No need of a semicolon after the after loop.

Comment: you tagged `jquery` but you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

do it with a `while` loop, it's easier.

I've used a specific variable for each involved value, included constants; that makes things easier too read (and is a good pratice too).

```
function brew() {

    // input values

    var lastTime = 15;        //military time for 3pm
    var lastCoffee = 150;     // 150mg of caffeine

    // constant

    var caffeineHalfLife = 5; // 5 hours  
    ver bedTimeCaffeine = 20; // 20mg of caffeine

    // variables

    var caffeine;
    var bedTime;

    // setup

    caffeine = lastCoffee;
    bedTime  = lastTime;

    // loop

    while( caffeine > bedTimeCaffeine ) {  // go on until caffeine > bedTimeCaffeine
        caffeine /= 2;                     // the caffeine value become half...
        bedTime += caffeineHalfLife;       // ...every 5 hours (caffeineHalfLife)
    }

}
```

but if you want to stick to `for` then the last part becomes

```
    // setup

    caffeine = lastCoffee;

    // loop

    for( bedTime = lastTime; caffeine > bedTimeCaffeine; bedTime += caffeineHalfLife ) {
        caffeine /= 2;
    }
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp for explanation of the `for` loop